# Flipping a view inside a container, revealing a second view

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

I am currently using this code:

```
FlipView *fv = [[FlipView alloc]init];
[UIView transitionWithView:flipContainer
                  duration:1
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{ 
                    [flipContainer addSubview:fv];
                }
                completion:NULL];
```

to flip a container view containing a UIImage around to reveal a second view (FlipView). FlipView is a UIView currently with its background set to red for debugging.

What happens now is that the container flips, but it's displaying the same thing as before, despite using:

```
[flipContainer addSubview:fv];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you add the subview without the animation? Does the subview appear? Maybe the subview isn't being initialized properly (such as maybe its frame isn't being set properly?)

You could try initializing like this:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin,yOrigin,width,height);
FlipView *fv = [[FlipView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Or try setting the frame property of the FlipView:

```
FlipView *fv = [[FlipView alloc]init];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin,yOrigin,width,height);
fv.frame = frame;
```

Comment: If I try to add the view without the animation, noting happens. It must be the frame. The container is 90*60, whereas the view is just a sub-class of UIView. What would I do to make it appear?

Comment: You could set the frame property of the FlipView, or you could initialize it with a frame. Try using xOrigin=0,yOrigin=0,width=90,height=60). Where are you setting the background color of the FlipView?

Comment: Thanks, that works! I tried doing it in the initWithFrame, but ended up just drawing a rect instead. To make it appear as though it's flipping over, I keep adding a new sub-view based on whether isPrimary is YES or NO. Is there a way to remove the current view before adding a new one, so that there is only one view onscreen at once? Currently, I'm just piling them on top of each other.

Comment: Nevermind, answered my own question! I used

                    for (UIView *subview in flipContainer.subviews) {
                                [subview removeFromSuperview];
                        }

Is this acceptable?

Comment: What's "isPrimary"? You can remove a subview from the containerView using [aSubiew removeFromSuperView]; (where aSubview is a pointer to the subview you want to remove). You can add that line of code to your animation block before you add the new subview.

Comment: Ah saw your new comment. Well that would remove all the subviews from the flipContainer view, so if that's what you want, that will work.

Comment: Yes, I have removed all subviews, then added the new one. Thanks for your help.